# Отслеживать только определённые каталоги и все файлы в корне репозитария git

Tags: git, gitignore

У меня есть git репозитарий. Он содержит много каталогов и файлов.

Я хочу, чтобы репозитарий включал только:

- определённые каталоги (bin, Documents);
- все файлы, которые находятся в корневом каталоге.

Мой `.gitignore` сейчас имеет вид:

```
/*
!/bin
!/Documents
/Documents/ViberDownloads
/Documents/.~lock*
!/.gitignore
!/.bash_aliases
!/.bash_history
!/.bashrc
!/.gitconfig
!/.profile
```

Сперва я всё исключаю `/*`.

Затем добавляю каталоги `bin`и `Documents` в "белый" список.

Исключаю из этих подкаталогов определённые данные (подкаталог `ViberDownloads` и временные файлы LibreOffice).

Теперь вручную добавляю по одному файлы из корневого каталога.

Но у меня таких файлов достаточно много. Неужели более простого способа добавить все файлы корня нет?

Comment: @alexander barakin, спасибо, точку забыл, когда копи-пастил с англ. версии. Не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос. Я хочу чтобы добавлялись два каталога - они добавляются. Я хочу чтобы все файлы в корне тоже добавлялись - они добавляются, но только если я вручную пишу !/имя_файла_в_корне. А я не хочу писать для каждого файла такую строку в .gitignore. Хочется найти короткий вариант, когда я одним шаблоном, сразу будут добавляться все файлы корня. Теперь понимаете?

Comment: Давайте по другому. Если я сейчас наберу в командной строке `git status`, то получу `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'`. Если я накидаю в корень новый каталогов и снова наберу `git status`, то получу тоже самое. То есть все папки, кроме bin и Documents будут неотслеживаемыми. Но мне хочется, чтобы все файлы в корня были отслеживаемыми. Сейчас это у меня выполняется только для следующих файлов: `.gitignore .bash_aliases .bash_history .bashrc .gitconfig .profile`. Я вижу пока только одно решение: для остальных файлов вручную добавлять строку в .gitignore. Но это очень плохое решение

Comment: Ещё попытка :-) Я хочу, чтобы отслеживались только 2 определённых каталога и все файлы в корневом каталоге. Но надо понимать, что в корневом каталоге файлы могут постоянно добавляться/удаляться/меняться. А править каждый раз `.gitignore` не очень хочется в этом случае.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77307/discussion-between-yura-shinkarev-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: всё, что было необходимо сказать, я уже сказал в комментариях: суть вашего вопроса неясна и вопрос требует корректировки. больше мне добавить нечего. удачи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит добавить слеш к первому правилу.

.gitignore:

```
/*/             ; Игнорируем все папки
!/Documents/    ; кроме Documents
!/bin/          ; и bin
```

Таким образом, файлы в корне не будут затронуты